# Is it possible to turn a normal date into an ISO 8601 time format?

Tags: php

I am trying to turn this type of format of the date:

> Thursday, November 10th, 2011 at 10:37 PM

Into an ISO 8601 format (with PHP). How can I do this? I've tried:

```
date("c", $row2['time'])
```

Obviously, that's not correct, because the timeago jQuery plugin is saying "41 years ago", and that is definitely not 41 years ago.

Is it not possible to turn that kind of date into the ISO 8601 format?

I've tried searching for this and I haven't found any solutions on how to turn this format into ISO 8601.

Comment: You should store it as the UTC timestamp, so you use it that way.

Comment: jQuery? What does that have to do with PHP?

Comment: @mc10 - I'm using a jQuery plugin to turn the date into "3 minutes ago", etc. so it is more understandable to the user. But it has to be in ISO 8601 format for it to work.

Comment: @CommunistPancake - Yeah, I was thinking about that. But before I do that, I wanted to see if this was possible first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a DateTime object, possibly created with [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat), or [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$date = 'Thursday, November 10th, 2011 at 10:37 PM';
$date = str_replace( 'at', '', $date);
echo date("c", strtotime( $date));
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/CdNKrY)

**Edit:** Here is a DateTime example using objects. Note that for both examples you should set a correct timezone from the list of [valid timezone strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

```
$date_obj = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'l, F jS, Y \at h:i A', 'Thursday, November 10th, 2011 at 10:37 PM', new DateTimeZone( 'America/New_York'));
echo $date_obj->format('c');
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/F4UkY8)

Comment: What happens if it doesn't have the 'th' on the number of the month? Will it still work correctly?

Comment: I just [tested](http://codepad.viper-7.com/H6T5KF) the `strtotime` and object oriented versions, they both will work correctly without the date suffix (th, rd, st, nd) in the input string.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again, but for some reason the timestamp it is producing is: `2011-11-23T00:00:00-05:00` See all those zeroes? It is causing the [timeago plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/) to say "2 hours ago" although it was only 20 minutes ago. Any ideas?

Comment: Just found the problem: the variable actually didn't have 'at' in it after all. I totally forgot I was adding that in myself with the echo. So really, I only have `$date`, `$time`, and `$date_short`. So, we're all good now.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$date = date('c', strtotime(str_replace(' at ', ' ', 'Thursday, November 10th, 2011 at 10:37 PM')));
echo $date;
```

[`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) parses your string and converts it into a Unix timestamp. [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) then reformats your date into an ISO 8601 date.

Comment: This returns `1970-01-01T10:00:00+10:00` for me.

Comment: `strtotime` chokes when it encounters the 'at' for me

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, which is probably why it's saying 41 years ago.

Comment: Actually, nickb beat me to the answer; his answer is more complete and should be accepted.